# htaccess rewrite urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a link http://mywebsite.com/?view=3457373673863568
everything after the view= will change depending on who gets it.
how can I redirect them to another page on the site i.e. http://mywebsite.com/mypage

something like:

RewriteRule http://mywebsite.com/?view=(?) http://mywebsite.com/mypage/

Answer (score 0):

`mod_rewrite` parses the URL and the rules only see the path, not the query string. The query string is stored in the variable `QUERY_STRING`, which needs to be matched separately.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=
RewriteRule ^$ /mypage [L]
```

This matches the empty path (i.e., `/` on your site) and any query string that starts with `view=`. The query string will be passed implicitly to the target page.

If you want an external redirect so the user browser shows `/mypage`, use the `[R]` flag (change `[L]` to `[L,R]`).